# Problem with asyncio in python script, cannot fetch telegram bot response

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, telegram, telethon

I wrote a python script which interacts with telegram bot.
it's working fine on my machine, but working weird on other computer

```
import platform
import asyncio
import re
from telethon import TelegramClient


if platform.system() == "Windows":
  asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())


client = TelegramClient("dtrend", api_id, api_hash)


async def main():

  await client.send_message(dtrend_bot_id, "/delete")
  delete_response = await get_last_message()
  await handle_start(delete_response)

  await handle_main()


async def handle_main():

  network_select_message = await get_last_message()
  await select_option(network_select_message, networks[network], 0)
...

async def get_last_message():
    history = await client.get_messages(bot_id)
    return history[0]

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

the problem is about fetching bot's reponse after sending message, or selecting option in bot's message.

this code works fine on my machine, with modules installed with 'python3 -m pip install --upgrade asyncio telethon'

but doesn't work on other machine, failing to fetch latest response of bot's messages,

I believe this issue is something to do with asyncio module, since I see the similar behaviour before I reinstalled modules with 'python3 -m pip install --upgrade asyncio telethon' on my machine. but for some reason this doesn't work on other machine.

I tried getting reponse with conversation context in telethon, but in this case, it fails to get response from option choose in bot's response, only getting response from send_message, I think just solving asyncio module issue will fix this problem.

I also tried setting up virtual environment for this script, but faced another strange behaviour that installing modules into the local environments installs different source of asyncio, which is with the issue, although it seems the versions are the same, the contents of the module is different.

FYI: I tested this on both Windows and Ubuntu on my machine.
target machine OS is Ubuntu

Comment: You shouldn't need to install `asyncio` with `pip` from PyPi. It's a built-in module in Python. So installing Python is enough to get it.